# Download xls file in app browser

Tags: web-services, cordova, ionic-framework, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I`m trying to load a excel file from a webservice using NgCordova In App Browser.
The webservice returns a Stream and I set the return content type to "application/vnd.ms-excel"
It seems to work when I use Chrome and Ripple but nothing happens when running from iOS or Android.

What am I doing wrong?

How can I make it work?

This is the piece of code to make the call to webservice:

```
var string = 'http://10.1.25.56/Triacao.WAP/SVCTriacaoMobile.svc/DownloadPlanilhaTreino?param1=test.xls';

                            $cordovaInAppBrowser
                                .open(string, '_blank')
                                .then(function (event) {
                                    // success
                                }, function (event) {
                                    // error
                                });
```

Comment: android can't open xls files with inAppBrowser, but that should work on iOS

Comment: Also make sure that you reach to your server with that address at is a little bit different case when you emulate it on your computer. You can check the reaching for example from logs of your server.

Comment: workaraund for android you mean? try with _system instead of _self, that should launch an intent to open apps installed that supports xls files

Comment: this is cordova. there is no intent

Comment: Ok guys, I made it work on iOS using inApp Browser but on Android and WP8 I get a blank/white screen.
Any solution for this?

Comment: yes, even using cordova there are intents. try with _system instead of _blank, that should launch an intent on android